# A high power RF amplifier design using an RFMD IC RF6886

Tags: amplifier

I am designing a high power RF amplifier using an RFMD IC, RF6886. This IC's operating frequency range is 100MHz-1000HMz. I am designing it for a frequency of 145MHz. I received a document from RFMD which contains the evaluation schematic for this IC within the frequency range of 135MHz-175MHz.

In this schematic, the RF components post the IC consist of 3 capacitors in parallel, then an inductor in series followed by 2 capacitors in parallel, another inductor in series, again 2 capacitors in parallel and finally a capacitor in series.

What is the significance of these lumped components? As far as I know, they together form a matching circuit for the IC, matching it's impedance to 50ohms. How exactly does this happen though? What variations in the values of the above components should I perform to match the impedance and in what manner? Is there some kind of standard method for matching using which I can meaningfully vary the values?

[image: Evaluation Schematic]

Comment: draw a schematic. It's not really intuitive to translate what you write "contains 4 caps in parallel, then an inductor in series, followed...". Especially it makes no sense to write that without giving component values and types – it makes a difference if those are 100pF film or 1 µF multilayer ceramic caps, and whether the relation between effective resistances in these components is around 1 or around 1 million.

Comment: *How exactly does this happen though?* Impedance matching is one of **THE** most critical parts in RF PA design. To learn about this start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching and note that that is just the basics. Experienced RF designers use hand calculations, simulations, sometimes EM simulators but always a  **network analyzer** to do proper impedance matching. In your circuit the network mainly works as a low-pass filter because of it's structure.

Comment: 600 pF on the output seems about 10x too high to my gut. Go check that the three caps connected to the output are correct. I don't think they are.

Answer (score 1):

They use multiple capacitors in parallel to get the desired total capacitance. You simply can't buy a 620 pF capacitor, but you can build one by using two 220 and one 180 pF cap in parallel.

Just add up the parallel capacitances and mentally treat them as one.

Then you're left with a classical LC low-pass. If you're building a power amplifier, you should definitely be sufficiently accustomed to these – otherwise, you **will** break the law by transmitting at frequencies you're not allowed to use, and that comes with something between expensive fines, shutdown of your lab, or even criminal charges (depending on what you interfered with, your jurisdiction and whether you should have known better (yes, you should)).